# Can't add service reference to client class for WCF project within same solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf

I'm working through an [example on a website](http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2014/05/calling-wcf-self-hosted-console-application.html) to create and consume a WCF service. I've created the service which is hosted in a windows application.

As per the instructions on the site I've created a ClientApp console app within in the same Visual Studio solution. Now the problem is that I cannot create a service reference to the WCF host project.

If I run the host project the Service is switched on and I can verify this by visiting the url in my browser. However, I cannot add a service reference to my client project while another project is running. The "Add Service Reference" option is greyed out. Presumably this is since they're in the same solution in Visual Studio.

If I try and add the reference when the host project is not running then I can get into the "Add Service Reference" screen but no services can be found (presumably because the WCF service is no longer running

How can I get around this?

The solution explorer is as in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could also try to start the WCF service in Visual Studio, then select "Detach All" from the Debug menu. This should let the service continue to run in the background, yet open Visual Studio to let you add service references.

Comment: or start without debugging to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

In the Add Service Reference dialog, click the Discover button and select Services in Solution:

[image]

Comment: It can't find any because I can only get into that dialog box if the service is not running

Comment: It shouldn't need to be running to discover a service in the solution - you need to click the little down arrow next to the discover button, and select 'Services in Solution

Comment: Tried it and got: "No Services found in the solution"

Comment: Ah, I see the problem - you created your StudentService project as a class library, rather than a WCF Service Library

Comment: This will help http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/2010/02/20/vs-net-add-service-reference-discover-service-does-not-work/

Comment: My project is console, and then it will be transfered to windows service, not a WCF service application... what should i do?